# No such file or directory in pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller

When I try to run a `.exe` file made with python, I get the following message:

> No such file or directory:
> 'C:\Users\[myUsername]\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI171122\tldextract\.tld_set'

What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure the file is there? The error says that the file doesn't exist there.